# MySQL: Limiting Number Of Records To 5 Unique Values In Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unique, limit

i am trying to create a leaderboard based on numbers of kills in a game where it shows top 5 ranking players (people with the same number of kills are in the same rank).

How do i get all records up until rank 5 position (all records until a max of 5 unique values in a column(kills)).

I hope that makes sense.

The query will also need to take into account the map. For Example: WHERE `map` = 'map_name'

For Example:

Table:

```
Name, Kills
user1 - 30
user2 - 27
user3 - 54
user4 - 34
user5 - 34
user6 - 27
user7 - 22
user8 - 22
user9 - 31
user10 - 21
user11 - 27
```

Result Needed (all players / records within the top 5 ranks):

```
1. user3 - 54
2. user4 - 34
   user5 - 34
3. user9 - 31
4. user1 - 30
5. user2 - 27
   user6 - 27
   user11 - 27
```

Answer (score 2):

Try query like that :-

```
select * from table where Kills in 
(select Kills from table group by Kills order by Kills desc limit 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables:

```sql
SELECT Name, Kills, rank
FROM (
   SELECT Name, Kills,
          @rank := IF (@k = Kills, @rank,
                     IF (@k:=Kills, @rank+1, @rank+1)) AS rank
   FROM scores
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @k := 0, @rank := 0) AS vars
   ORDER BY Kills DESC ) AS t
WHERE t.rank <= 5
```

`@rank` variable calculates the ranking position of each row as rows are processed in descending `Kills` order.

A nice feature of this query is that you can also get the ranking position of each row in the output (as noted by @Juan Carlos).

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59807/1)

Comment: You should include the rank in the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable
 WHERE Kills IN (SELECT DISTINCT Kills 
                 FROM YourTable 
                 ORDER BY Kills DESC 
                 LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY Kills DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select kills, name from table where Kills in (select distinct Kills from table order by Kills desc limit 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.Name, s.Kills FROM scores as s 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Kills From scores ORDER BY Kills DESC LIMIT 5) as s1 
ON s.Kills = s1.Kills  
ORDER BY s.Kills DESC
```